# Serverless Cognito - Sign Up with Username, Password, and Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am having trouble implementing Cognito via Serverless. The AWS Cognito documentation is poor. What I want to do is:

- Allow user to sign up with a unique username (coolprogrammer69), a unique email, and password
- After sign up, allow user to modify username (coolprogrammer69 -> awesomeprogrammer69) and email as long as it is unique

This is a typical auth flow for a forum website like Stackoverflow; however, I cannot find the right combination of attributes to make this a reality. Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
service: my-cool-infrastructure

package:
  individually: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  environment:
    user_pool_id: { Ref: UserPool }
    client_id: { Ref: UserClient }
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth
        - cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser
        - cognito-idp:AdminSetUserPassword
      Resource: "*"
functions:
  login:
    handler: user/login.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/login
          method: post
          cors: true

  register:
    handler: user/register.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/register
          method: post
          cors: true

  privateAPI:
    handler: user/private.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: user/private
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: PrivateAuthorizer
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            arn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - UserPool
                - Arn
            claims:
              - email
resources:
  Resources:
    UserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: my-cognito-pool
        Schema:
        -
          Name: email
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        -
          Name: preferred_username
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 8
            RequireNumbers: true
            RequireSymbols: true


    UserClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: user-pool-ui
        GenerateSecret: false
        UserPoolId: { Ref: UserPool }
        AccessTokenValidity: 5
        IdTokenValidity: 5
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
          - "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"
```